# Unable to delete tableview row with button and JSON data in Swift

Tags: json, swift, button, tableview

I am getting JSON data successful and when i click `cancelTapped` button.. then.. service is deleted from JSON but in tableview row is still showing, why

after cancel the service i need not to show the row

code: here `cancelid` is which service i need to delete from tableview that sevice id

```
var cancelid: String?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
tableView.reloadData()
}
func deleteServiceCall(){

print("cancel id : \(cancelid)")

let param = ["wishlist_id" : cancelid]
APIReqeustManager.serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.delete_request, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false) { [weak self] (resp) in
    if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
        let success = code["status"] as? [String : Any]
        if success == "Success"{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?.count ?? 0
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fundTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FundTableViewCell

let indexData = wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?[indexPath.row]

cancelid = String(indexData?.id ?? 0)
cell.cancelBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelTapped(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

return cell

}


@objc func cancelTapped(sender: UIButton) {

self.showTwoButtonAlertWithLeftAction(title: "WithDraw", buttonTitleLeft: "Yes", buttonTitleRight: "Cancel", message: "Do you want to remove this withdrawel Request!?") {
    self.deleteServiceCall()
}
}
```

Comment: Issue is that you may be removing request b y you are not updating datasource i.e, `wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?`. You should update `wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?`variable as well before reloading cell on cancel API success.

Comment: @Kudos what is datasource, is it service call.. how to update.. pls do guide

Comment: @if i do like this befor reload `self?.wishlistServicecall()`.. then one more service is adding

Comment: Definitely It will. So dont use that just check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[String : Any]` compared to a `String` always fails.

The value of `status` is most likely a String.

And you have to remove the item also from the data source array.

```
if let code = resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any], 
    let success = code["status"] as? String, success == "Success" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let index = self?.wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?.firstIndex(of: {$0.id == cancelid}) {
               self?.wishlistData?.result?.wishlist?.remove(at: index)
               self?.tableView.removeRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            }
        }
}
```

Note: You should declare the data source array as non-optional empty array to get rid of all those optionals.

Comment: okay, i have done like your answer.. but here when i tap `cancelTapped `  `self?.tableView.reloadData()` is not hitting.. to delete row from table.. but in JSON response service is deleted.. whats the issue?

Comment: You have to remove the item also from the data source array

Comment: how? tableview is hitting but cell is not removing

Comment: You have to remove the item from `wishList`. Get the index of the item by `cancelId` and call `remove(at:)`.

Comment: error: `Value of type 'Array<wishlist>??' has no member 'firstIndex'`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer get rid of the optionals. There are too many question marks.

Comment: could you plz answer here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729900/how-to-change-clicked-cell-button-label-with-json-response-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You need to update datasource before `self?.tableView.reloadData()`.

```
  APIReqeustManager.serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.delete_request, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false) { [weak self] (resp) in
    if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
        let success = code["status"] as? [String : Any]
        if success == "Success"{
         //Before reloading tableView we should update datashouce i.e, variable you are storing data like:
            wishlistData?.result?.wishlist = resp.dic[""]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```