# How to change clicked cell button label with JSON response in swift

Tags: json, swift, button, tableview

In my tableview cell i added `awerdedBtnLabel` and `awardedBtn`.. if i tap button on any one cell then i need to change only tapped cell label text

**code for tableview:** with the below code if i click on any one cell `awardedBtn` then all cells `awerdedBtnLabel` text is changing, why?

**how to change label text only on clicked cell**, please do guide me

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return viewproposalData?.result?.bids?.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewProposalTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewProposalTableVIewCell


let bidData = viewproposalData?.result?.bids?[indexPath.row]
cell.propAmt.text = "$\(bidData?.amount ?? "")"

cell.awardedBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.awardedBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

let postServData = viewproposalData?.result?.posted_services
if postServData?.is_awarded == "Y"{
    cell.awerdedBtnLabel.text = "Rewoke Award"
    cell.milestoneView.isHidden = false

}else{
    cell.awerdedBtnLabel.text = "Award"
    cell.milestoneView.isHidden = true
}

return cell
}

@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){


}
```

**EDIT:** according [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494) answer i have tried like below.. but nothing changing now.. i mean not all cells or not a single.. the button label text remains same.. if i tap on any button then no change in label

```
class ViewProposalTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

 var onAwardBtn: ((_ isAwarded: String) -> Void)?
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewproposalData?.result?.bids?.count ?? 0//5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewProposalTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewProposalTableVIewCell

 let postServData = viewproposalData?.result?.posted_services

 let isAwarded = postServData?.is_awarded

    cell.onAwardBtn = { [weak self] (isAwarded) in

        if isAwarded == postServData?.is_awarded {
            
            cell.awerdedBtnLabel.text = "Rewoke Award"
            cell.milestoneView.isHidden = false
         
        }
        else{
            cell.awerdedBtnLabel.text = "Award"
            cell.milestoneView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

**2nd Edit:**

JSON response from console:

```
JSON {
    jsonrpc = "2.0";
    result =     {
        bids =       (
                        {
                amount = 100;
                id = 153;

                "get_bid_user" =                 {
                    address = dfsdffafadf;
                };
               
            },
        );
        "posted_services" =         {
            "is_awarded" = Y;
        };
    };
    }
```

Comment: Rather than *objective-c-ish* protocol/delegate use a callback closure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378515/issue-detecting-button-cellforrowat/46379494#46379494)

Comment: @vadian how is my question is related to your mentioned answer? you may be right but i am not able to understand

Comment: @vadian i am not getting selected index for `postServData?.is_awarded`.. if i tap on any one `awardedBtn` then label text changing in all cells ... thats the issue

Comment: @vadian, i have added my try with ur answer at the bottom of my post.. if there is a chance could u guide me please

Comment: It's unclear how `postServData` is related to the data source (array). You are reading the sane value in each call of `cellForRowAt`. And to become persistent you have to maintain the `awarded` state in the data source somewhere. By the way I told you (in one of your other accounts) to get rid of the unnecessary optional chaining by declaring the data source as non-optional. For example `viewproposalData?.result?.bids?.count ` is terrible.

Comment: @vadian. i have added my JSON response in my 2nd edit in my question.. here i need to change cell button text according to `is_awarded `.. could you help me know

Comment: @vadian sure i will check my optionals in my code

Comment: any developer if you are going through my question.. please take a moment and help

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear. `bids` is an array, so does the `award` state apply to all items in the array? And as I said you have to **save** the state in the model after changing it.